# Transfer files between VPC and Host Machine

Tags: windows, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a virtual machine setup and I am able to transfer files from the host to the vpc and from the vpc to the host.  I then copied the vpc to another machine and I am not able to copy files anymore.  How can you setup the ability to copy files between the VPC and the host machine.

Comment: Which Virtual technology do you use?

Comment: Are you using shared folders?  How were you transferring files before?

Answer (score 1):

There might be two reasons:

1. The VM doesn't have access to the network
2. The user account on the VM has no permissions on the host.

You'll need to give us more details if you wish a better answer, like what software are you using and which error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of work-arounds; I know they are not ideal, but a way to get the files out if you need to...

- Email it to yourself
- Use Dropbox or Skydrive or another similar syncing technology
- Use USB flash drive or external hard drive...

Anyways, hope you find a solution!